# Chrome Developer Tools closes instantly when attempting to debug WebDriver E2E test

Tags: debugging, selenium, webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I usually debug my Selenium tests in Chrome's dev tools panel. However, after upgrading my OS (Ubuntu Linux), my E2E tests broke completely: Chrome didn't open the first page, but sat idle showing only a blank page. Eventually I upgraded [ChromeDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver), and now the tests work again. But with this new Chrome version (after the OS upgrade) and with this new ChromeDriver, there's a weird problem with the dev tools window:

Whenever I click *CTRL + SHIFT + I* to open the dev tools window, or click *Tools -> Developer Tools* in Chrome's menu, the dev tools window flashes open, but then closes instantly. It looks blank and empty, the 1/10 seconds it's visible. This has really never happened before.

When I manually open another tab in [the Chrome instance that's being driven by WebDriver], and navigate to e.g. *http://www.google.se/*, then, when I open the dev tools window in that tab, it usually stays open (but not always). — It's mainly [the dev tools window for the browser tab that is being controlled by the Chrome Driver] that closes instantly.

However if I hold town CTRL+SHIFT+I for a while, this genereates many many "clicks", and then the dev tools suddenly stays open, sometimes. But after 10-20 seconds it suddenly closes again.

Why is Chrome doing this? How can I have it stop?

<sub>Chrome Version 29.0.1547.57

Chrome Driver versions 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2 tested (and problem present).

Selenium 2.35.0, and version 2.25.0 (I think it was) also didn't work.</sub>

Comment: We are experiencing the same thing with ChromeDriver 2.2 on OSX. Not much info out there on this problem, which is a pretty frustrating one.

Comment: @MattGreer A very weird problem. I tested ChromeDriver 2.0 and 2.1 as well, in addition to 2.2. The problem was present in all those versions.

Comment: Here is the bug report for it: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=483  along with their disappointing response

Comment: It seems like the sensible thing to do would be to handle the exception and pass control over to the dev tool if possible

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Chrome isn't doing this; ChromeDriver 2 is. ChromeDriver 2 and the DevTools windows both compete for the same automation channel, and ChromeDriver automatically closes the DevTools window in order for it to work.

See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing for more info

Also see the related issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=483

Comment: Interesting fact if you set a break-point in the test or stop the test its possible to open and use the debugger tool in chrome.

Comment: @ColacX can you explain how you did that?

Comment: You mean set a breakpoint in visual studio editor while running the test? I think you can figure that out.

Comment: Just tested and still works in Chrome 52. Just put 'debugger' somewhere in your code, and make sure the line gets executed