# Using the console with Selenium Webdriver.Chrome() cause Exceptions

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Selenium webdriver 2.38.4, Chromium 37.0 & chromedriver 2.10.
I run a basic script:

```
chrome_options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,
                              executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

once I start looking around at the console of Chrome the next set of commands I try `(driver.title, driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body') )` will result with:

> WebDriverException: Message: u"unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw
>   exception:
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null\n  (Session info:
>       chrome=37.0.2062.94)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267517,
>       platform=Linux 3.5.0-45-generic x86)

Anybody knows why this is happening? Its kind of hard reloading everytime just for it to work correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a known issue (expected behaviour for ChromeDriver) with work-around currently. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18420769/363701)'s answer for more info

Comment: thanks for the information, it's always nice to know more about a problem :)

Answer (score 8):

Its happening because your console is open at the browser. Just close it and you won't see this error again.

Comment: How to fix it, that it would be possible to use?

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to fix it yet. But it should get fixed on the new versions of ChromeDriver.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ricardo,even u face similar kind of issue like 'Element not visible' or the error u mentioned 'unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception:',u can resolve it by minimizing u r chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

May, (or may not!) help, but when I've had this error on other elements, I have got round it by giving the element that I'm searching for a name and id.

Not really appropriate for a body tag, however if it means you can run your tests.

I'm assuming of course, that you're testing something that you can alter.