# how to keep opened developer tools while running a selenium nightwatch.js test?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am starting to write e2e tests using nightwatch.js and I noticed some errors that I would like to inspect manually in the target browser's console (developer tools). but always when I open the developer console, it is automatically closed by the browser. is this a intended feature of either selenium or nightwatch.js, and, if it is the case, how can I disable it?

Comment: Which browser are you testing?

Comment: I am testing with firefox and chrome on Ubuntu. In the case of Chrome, I tried with right click + inspect element and with the F12 Key, but always got the same flashing of the developers tools.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible. See [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing):

> When you open the DevTools window, ChromeDriver is automatically
>   disconnected. When ChromeDriver receives a command, if disconnected,
>   it will attempt to close the DevTools window and reconnect.
>
> Chrome's DevTools only allows one debugger per page. As of 2.x,
>   ChromeDriver is now a DevTools debugging client. Previous versions of
>   ChromeDriver used a different automation API that is no longer
>   supported in Chrome 29.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18420769/954442).

Comment: I highly appreciate your answer, I just was completely lost about even how to properly search for documentation about the issue, and you pointed me in a direction that helped me to increase my understanding of the whole testing pipeline. Anyway I wanna try  user3613154 suggestion before marking any answer as accepted.

Comment: This is most disappointing. Thanks for the quality info though.

Comment: guys, make sure you see the better answer below~

Answer (score 25):

I'm successfully using this config in nightwatch:

```
...

chrome: {
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    acceptSslCerts: true,
    chromeOptions: {
      'args': ['incognito', 'disable-extensions', 'auto-open-devtools-for-tabs']
    }
  }
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve this using Node Inspector: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

Put a `debugger` statement where you want the test to pause and run `node-debug ./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch --config path/to/nightwatch.json --test yourTest.js`