# How to Send Keys before loading URL in Selenium Chromedriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to send F12 key before loading the URL using Selenium Chromedriver in python? Any suggestion would be really helpful for my project.

Comment: Yes I also found out that even if we open devtools it will be closed as soon as some operation is done with Chromedriver. Anyway thanks for your replies. 
I was actually trying to download HAR from Network tab of devtools by this method since BrowserMobProxy are not compatable with QUIC,SPDY and https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-har-capturer has a bit problem that I need to download HAR for Youtube videos of unknown duration and chrome-har-capturer does not have that feature yet. So if anyone knows how to do this please reply because I am stuck on this for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You can send key strokes to the `body` tag regardless of the page your on. So just send the key before navigating (in C#):

```
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).SendKeys(Keys.F12);
```

Another option is to use `Actions` class:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.SendKeys(Keys.F12).Perform();
```

Comment: SendKeys is not working for me with F keys or ESC for example. For strings it works.

Answer (score 1):

Chromedriver itself uses devtools so the devtools themselves cannot be open when using selenium. Even if you do get them open with F12 they will immediately close once you perform an action with selenium + chromedriver

Answer (score 1):

There i s one alternate solution to send keys `f12` before opening a URL

Use `Robot` class (In Java) in this way-

```
driver =new ChromeDriver();
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F12); 
robot.delay(2000);
driver.get(your_Site_URL);
```

It will send the `F12` keys but the developer tool will close on next page visit.

If you want to keep Developer tool remain open which is not possible
For reference [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343090/how-to-keep-opened-developer-tools-while-running-a-selenium-nightwatch-js-test).