# Automatically Run a Script in my Browser console after opening a link using Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome-devtools

I want to run some JavaScript in my browser DevTools console. So far, I have opened up a specific website only through it. Can it be done in Python?

Right now, I am using the following code:

```
url = 'http://some-website.com/'

webbrowser.open(url)
```

What I want to do now is open up the DevTools console panel and then run a script through it automatically? Can it be done by using Python or some other tool along with Python?

Answer (score 0):

I don't belive this can be done, as

> ChromeDriver 2 and the DevTools windows both compete for the same
>   automation channel, and ChromeDriver automatically closes the DevTools
>   window in order for it to work.

See here for more: [Chrome Developer Tools closes instantly when attempting to debug WebDriver E2E test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420769/chrome-developer-tools-closes-instantly-when-attempting-to-debug-webdriver-e2e-t)